# Why is this skipping one row of cells?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a macro that filters a spreadsheet by department and then copies & paste the results into the appropriate departments worksheet.  It then repeats for each of the 9 departments. It is working fine except it doesn't copy and paste the last line of the data for the "Punch Press" section. It shows the cells highlighted but the data does not transfer with it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's what I have:

```
Sub UpdateTables()
  'PunchPress Macro



    Sheets("Audit scores").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AL$118").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        "Punch Press ESP"


    Range("X1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select


    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Punch Press").Select
    Range("X1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 17.57
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 20.57
    Rows("2:2").RowHeight = 15
    Selection.RowHeight = 15

    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Usually when you filter the underlying data is still there.  I wonder if you're copying hidden cells.  Have you stepped through the code with the debugger to see what Selection is right before you copy it?  Also, this looks like a macro recording, this could go a lot faster if you addressed sheets/cells directly instead of using ActiveSheet, Selection, .Select, and Copy.Paste.  `Sheets("Punch Press").Range("X1").Text = Sheets("Audit scores").Range("X1").Offset(1,1).Text` ... and that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you where using `Range(..)` in an incorrect manner. I believe you to be assuming this enforces the range to be on the active sheet but this is incorect. When I run this I get an error.

I've update your code to run but without any performance enhancements. The below worked for me.

```
Sub UpdateTables()
'PunchPress Macro

    With Sheets("Audit scores")
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<~~Remove filters
        .Range("$A$1:$AL$118").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Punch Press ESP"
        .Range("X1").Select
        .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    End With

    Selection.Copy

    With Sheets("Punch Press")
        .Select
        .Range("X1").Select
        .Paste
        .Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 17.57
        .Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 20.57
        .Rows("2:2").RowHeight = 15
        Selection.RowHeight = 15
        .Range("A1").Select
    End With

End Sub
```

To add in a little optimisation to the copying of your values. The copy method is the best because your filtered the sheet but this can be done in one line. I've also retrieved the last row and column for use instead of relying on the selecting down and right as this will stop on an empty cell.

```
Sub UpdateTables()
'PunchPress Macro

    Dim rs As Long, cs As Long

    With Sheets("Audit scores")
        rs = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row
        cs = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Column 
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<~~Remove filters
        .Range("$A$1:$AL$118").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Punch Press ESP"
        .Range(.Cells(1, "X"), .Cells(rs, cs)).Copy Sheets("Punch Press").Range("X1")
    End With

    With Sheets("Punch Press")
        .Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 20.57
        .Rows("1:2").RowHeight = 15
        .Activate
        .Range("A1").Select
    End With

End Sub
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I applied the optimized code and it is faster but it only copies the header row into the new sheets.

Comment: Two things. 1: Be sure there's data of that filter. 2: You may need to clear the filter first then apply the new filter.